# iOS 5 Storyboards and Nibs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, storyboard

I have started my iOS 5 app using a storyboard, however if I want to programatically modally present a view, how can I? I can't use `initWithNibName` as there are no longer nob files, but a storyboard.

E.g. this will give me a blank UINavigationView and not my Interface Builder one:

```
setupView = [[setupController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:setupView];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

If I use a button in interface builder (in my storyboard) and link the two views with it using 'Modal' it works a charm, but I want to do it programatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I think I have been looking for `performSegueWithIdentifier` and it works a charm.

Comment: Howdid youdo that? I mean, it asks for a sender (id)sender and That gets me confused. How do I tell the navigationController that the sender is the "+" button that I also created programatically ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, simply use `self` for the id and it will pickup the link from Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was looking for HOURS together trying to figure this out! Thank you!

Comment: if you want a quick reference FAQ on storyboard: http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/faq-on-ios5-storyboard/

Answer (score 6):

[Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5 Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) explained everything  in details.

Comment: Its very helpful, but it doesn't help me present the view I designed in my storyboard programatically. The guide only ever talks about changing view from inside Interface Builder.